# How to filter's by id in Dart? Not searching bar

Tags: flutter, dart, filter

guys, I am trying to make filter by using id's of item. I have researched a lot, but I think I am missing something obvious. So as I said i need to make a filtration, I have API where two different models Transport and Marshes. Each clasess contains id of bus, tram, subway. For the bus id = 1, for tram = 2, for sunbway id = 3 and for each of these separate id's API contains the 3 separate list of bus' numbers, tram's numbers and subway's train numbers.

I create two models and two screen:

**The models**

```
class TransportType {
  TransportType({
    this.ttId,
    this.ttTitle,
    this.ttNote,
  });

  final int ttId;
  final String ttTitle;
  String ttNote;
}
```

Also I also clearly indicated that I need the ID of the route in the link from the API. Now it look like so:

For **Marshes** it is:

```
Future<List<Marshes>> fetchMarshes() async {
 final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
          'http:/getMarshes.php?fmt=json&tt_id'),
      body: {'tt_id': '1'}, headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth}, );
```

For fetching **Transport** model it looks like this:

```
Future<List<TransportType>> fetchTranspotes() async {
  var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'http://getTransportTypes.php?fmt=json'),
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
  var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
  return jsonResponse
      .map((transport) => TransportType.fromJson(transport))
      .toList();
}
```

For fetching the both list: List of Transport types and List of Numbers I am using FutureBuilder:
The srceen one for **Transport Types** looks like so:

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<TransportType>>(
          future: futureTransposrt,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (builder, index){
                  TransportType project = snapshot.data[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(project.ttId.toString()),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MarshId(ttId: 1,)), (route) => false);
                },
```

In the conctructor of MarshId I put the values I want, so the second sreen also has the same conctructor and it looks like this:

```
class MarshId extends StatefulWidget {
  
 final int ttId;

  const MarshId({Key key, this.ttId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarshIdState createState() => _MarshIdState();
}
```

So my qiestions is pretty dumb: **What am I doing wrong?** I did everything as docs say and I reserched here on SO, but it dosen't work and I copmpletly don't understand what I am doing wrong. I also used this expression as here reccomend but now it seems like it is not work:`marshes = marshes.where((marsh) => marsh.ttId == ttId).toList()`; I understand this task: I need to filter the data by category and when the user clicks on certain transport type, for example, "bus", he gets to the screen where there is only a list of bus numbers. But I can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong when I write filtering.

I really appreciate your help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass id to other page by using constructor in your `ListBus()` class the you simply use where like this
ie. let's say you parameter name is ttId;
then your filter will be

```dart
marshes = marshes.where((marsh) => marsh.ttId == ttId).toList();
```